# What is the complete list of formatting strings for Dates in groovy?

Tags: date, groovy, formatting

Where can I find a list of all formatting strings that Groovy can use when outputting a date?  The Groovy documentation seems to be very sparse on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) are probably a good place to start

Comment: And I have no idea why I couldn't find that earlier today.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Go look up the formatting information for java.util.[Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).  There's a very long list of formatters and what they do.